# How to make OpenVPN to autoreconnect to gateway at any time

Tags: linux, bash, cron, openvpn

I've recently discovered a built-in way to have OpenVPN to auto connect to VPN gateway on startup, which is via setting profiles .conf files in `/etc/default/openvpn` as a part of `AUTOSTART` parameter. Well, it works like a charm, but what is a good way to reconnect to OpenVPN if the connection is dropped?

I am rather new to Linux, so my implementation is basically a bash script with do while, which checks if it can ping the OpenVPN gateway's IP, and if it can't it `sudo`' the `openvpn --config /path/to/ovpn` to reconnect.

Could you please advise a more reliable way to have the connection reestablished by the host automatically?

Answer (score 8):

From 'man openvpn':

> --ping-restart n Similar to --ping-exit, but trigger a SIGUSR1 restart after n seconds pass without reception of a ping or other packet from
>   remote.
>
> This option is useful in cases where the remote peer has a dynamic IP
>   address and a low-TTL DNS name is used to track the IP address using 
>   a  service such as http://dyndns.org/ + a dynamic DNS client such as
>   ddclient.
>
> If the peer cannot be reached, a restart will be triggered, causing
>   the hostname used with --remote to be re-resolved (if --resolv-retry
>   is also spec‐ ified).
>
> In server mode, --ping-restart, --inactive, or any other type of
>   internally generated signal will always be  applied  to  individual 
>   client  instance objects, never to whole server itself.  Note also in
>   server mode that any internally generated signal which would normally
>   cause a restart, will cause the deletion of the client instance object
>   instead.
>
> In client mode, the --ping-restart parameter is set to 120 seconds by
>   default.  This default will hold until the client pulls a replacement
>   value from the server, based on the --keepalive setting in the server
>   configuration.  To disable the 120 second default, set --ping-restart
>   0 on the client.
>
> See the signals section below for more information on SIGUSR1.
>
> Note that the behavior of SIGUSR1 can be modified by the
>   --persist-tun, --persist-key, --persist-local-ip, and --persist-remote-ip options.
>
> Also note that --ping-exit and --ping-restart are mutually exclusive
>   and cannot be used together.

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned, my connection is triggered by AUTOSTART parameter. I don't have a place to explicitly add --ping-restart. How can I have the openvpn deamon to autostart per configuration and do --ping-restart?

Comment: Also from the man page: "OpenVPN allows any option to be placed either on the command line or in a configuration file.  Though all command line options are preceded by a double-leading-dash ("--"), this prefix can be removed when an option is placed in a configuration file."

You place the ping-restart command in the /etc/default/openvpn/*.conf files that you created in order to list them in the AUTOSTART variable in /etc/default/openvpn.

Comment: `ping-restart 0` should be specified in conf files in `/etc/openvpn` not `/etc/default/openvpn`